# Google Colab: playground mode vs "normal mode"

Tags: google-colaboratory

When a person shares a Google Colab notebook with me, it is opened in playground mode and it shows a button for "Copy to Drive", on clicking this it opens another window with same code which I call the "normal mode".

Playground mode has Tesla P4 GPUs while "normal mode" has Tesla T4 GPUs, which I found after hours of debugging and there is no mention of this in the references I came across. Why is there a difference between these two modes?

Answer (score 1):

The GPU type isn't guaranteed or related to any particular mode. Quoting from the [Colab FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html):

> Colab is able to provide free resources in part by having dynamic
>   usage limits that sometimes fluctuate, and by not providing guaranteed
>   or unlimited resources. This means that overall usage limits as well
>   as idle timeout periods, maximum VM lifetime, GPU types available, and
>   other factors vary over time. Colab does not publish these limits, in
>   part because they can (and sometimes do) vary quickly.

If you're interested in priority access to the fastest GPU types, you might consider subscribing to [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup).